# How to read Capacitance Table?

Tags: capacitor

I bought a [30pF Variable Trimmer Capacitor](https://www.ebay.com/itm/183301843141?ul_noapp=true), but am unsure how to adjust it. The lowest capacitance I am getting by adjusting the screw is 50pf, and it doesn't seem to matter which way I turn it. I contacted the seller again to get more info about the range (I need 2-22pf for my fm transmitter project) and he sent me this image, which I don't know how to read. I would really appreciate a pair of more experienced eyes telling me if this is the right capacitor (COLOR GREEN) for my project

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you measuring the capacitance? It doesn't take much to pick up 10's of pF of stray capacitance, and measuring single digit pF capacitors isn't easy.

The green body 30pF cap has a range of 6.2pF (maximum that you can expect the lowest capacitance to be) to 30pF +50/-10% (range you can expect the maximum to be, or 27pF to 45pF).

So it does not appear to be suitable to get your minimum capacitance required, especially if you have to account for some layout and other stray capacitance in your circuit. You might consider re-design of your circuit so that the minimum capacitance required isn't so low.

Answer (score 1):

The green trimmer has a guaranteed range from 6.2 pF to 27 pF, so you may not get down to 2 pF with this component.

We can't comment on your measured values without knowing how you made the measurement.